# Why did my Firefox spell checker mark "realize" and "analyze" as misspelled?

Tags: firefox, spell-check

The suggestions it gave were "realise" and "analyse", so I went to the [COCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_of_Contemporary_American_English) (The Corpus of Contemporary American English), and it turned out that what I've spelled was most commonly spelled, and what Firefox suggested. Well, I might just say they were the rare cases. Why is that?

Answer (score 11):

Firefox is suggesting British spellings to you. Is your browser set to use en-GB for some reason? (Or en-CA, or anything other than en-US.)

Comment: I know this doesn't belong to the English.SE, but since since this is related: to change the language being used by Firefox's spell checker, right click within any text field, and under languages choose the one you want. If it's not listed, new dictionaries can be added by clicking the 'Add Dictionary' link.

Comment: @trVoldemort - Australian English uses "proper" ;) English spellings.

Comment: I have changed my language from en-us to en-ie and it still spell checks in American...

Comment: Yes, but for a more operational answer: Where and how can this be checked in Firefox? What are the actual steps to get this information? (Please edit your answer instead of responding in comments.) And probably the OP's *real* question is how this can be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

*Realize* and *Analyze* are the *American* versions of the *British Realise* and *Analyse*.
The word 'analyse' has its roots from the word 'analysis', and I think the usage 'analyse' is more etymologically correct.
Some editors may not **recognize (recognise)** the variants, no need to worry :)

For more info, [check this link](http://www3.telus.net/linguisticsissues/BritishCanadianAmerican.htm).

Comment: American English spelling is often closer to Spanish (which has *realizar* and *analizar*) while British English is closer to French (*réaliser* and *analyser*), and also with Webster's improvements such as *color*.